# Core i5 4200u, can it handle Ubuntu?

Tags: 15.10, 16.04

i'm running Windows 10 on a laptop, upgraded from 8 to 8.1 then 10, cpu is
core i5 4200u, can it handle Ubuntu?

if i installed 15.10, can i upgrade to 16.04 LTS when it comes out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your i5 can surely handle ubuntu 15.10 and 16.04. I have an i3-4030u running ubuntu 15.10 and its blazing fast. And also you will be able to upgrade from 15.10 to 16.04 when it comes available to public.

Answer (score 0):

yes, [ubuntu system requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) recommends 1GHz and 2Gb ram for gui usage, so a core i5 should be no problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

[Yes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements), though you do not mention a lot of specifics e.g. GPU and [yes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu)